# Counting gap sizes in a subfamily of partitions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

Let $\mathcal{OD}$ be the set of all odd and distinct integer partitions. This has a generating function given by
$$\sum_{\lambda\vdash\mathcal{OD}}q^{\vert\lambda\vert}=\prod_{j\geq1}(1+q^{2j-1})$$
where $\vert\lambda\vert$ stand for the sum of the parts $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots$ of $\lambda$.

Define the sequence of number $s(\lambda):=\#\{i: \lambda_i-\lambda_{i+1}>2\}$.

Is there a formula as a bivariate generating function for the below sum?
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\mathcal{OD}} x^{s(\lambda)}q^{\vert\lambda\vert}=$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that the  partition has $m$ elements we  have to select
$m-1$ gaps between consecutive values  (even ones). The first gap
contributes $m-1$  times to the  sum, the second one  $m-2$ times
and  gap number  $m-1$ contributes  one time.  The initial  value
contributes $m$ times.  This yields

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} 
(q^m + q^{3m} + q^{5m}+ \cdots)
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1}
(q^{2(m-p)} + x q^{4(m-p)} + x q^{6(m-p)} + \cdots)
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 1} 
q^m (1 + q^{2m} + q^{4m} + \cdots)
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} q^{2(m-p)}
(1 + x q^{2(m-p)} + x q^{4(m-p)} + \cdots)
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 1} q^m \frac{1}{1-q^{2m}}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} q^{2(m-p)}
\left(1 + x \frac{q^{2(m-p)}}{1-q^{2(m-p)}}\right)
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{q^m}{1-q^{2m}}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} q^{2p}
\left(1 + x \frac{q^{2p}}{1-q^{2p}}\right).$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{q^{m^2}}{1-q^{2m}}
\prod_{p=1}^{m-1} 
\left(1 + x \frac{q^{2p}}{1-q^{2p}}\right).}$$

Comment: Good start. Your formula expands: $q + q^3 + q^4 + q^5 + xq^6 + q^7 + (x + 1)q^8 + 2q^9 + 2xq^10+\cdots$, so I was wondering if this gives what we want. For example, there are two partitions $91$ and $73$ for $n=10$. What does the coefficient $2x$ of $q^{10}$ tell us? Are you considering the last summands in partitions because it contributes to $s(\lambda)$ unless it equals $1$? That is if $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m)$ then $\lambda_{m+1}=0$.

Comment: It says there are two partitions from the desired class with one gap that is larger than two -- $2 \times x^1$ and indeed these are $(3,7)$ and $(1,9).$ I am ordering them from smallest to largest. For example the coefficient on $q^{24}$ is $2x^2+7x+2$ so there are $7$ partitions with one gap larger than two. I suggest you verify this, possibly with a CAS.

Comment: True. Thank you. Apparently you have excluded the last (smallest) $\lambda_m$ from this calculations. How does the formula changes if we would like to engage $\lambda_m$ by the convention that $\lambda_{m+1}=0$?

Comment: We would have to adapt the first factor, as I am going from smallest to largest. So you precede everything by a zero term. Then the first gap is equal to the first constituent  which then has to be at least three. I leave it to you to adapt the formula (looks like replacing $q^{m^2}$ by $q^{m^2+2m}$ should do it) and merge it into your post so it does not get closed. Thanks! Going off line for the day.

Comment: Replace $q^m+q^{3m}+q^{5m}+\cdots$ by $q^m+xq^{3m}(1+q^{2m}+q^{4m}+\cdots) = q^m+x\frac{q^{3m}}{1-q^{2m}}.$